# Can I hide the form using javaScript when a PHP form has been submitted and the page refreshes?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I have a form that is created in PHP and I've been doing the front end styling to it. When the form is submitted the page refreshes and a message is displayed.
The message is displayed above the form - but the user shouldn't be able to interact with the form once it's submitted - or see it! Just see the confirmation message.
I have no idea where to start with this or why this is happening.
Can someone send me in the right direction?

Comment: Same logic you use to know to display a message would be what you use not to display the form

Comment: The message displaying the message is written in the back-end. Could you give me a hand in the right direction on what's happening?

Comment: Right. So there  would be no form output then. Unless user may need to use form again? `if($submitted){ // echo message}else{//echo form}`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand.
Can you explain like I'm 5? 

```{% import "forms.html" as forms %} {% if (confirmation) %}
<p>Thank you for your enquiry. A Sales representative will contact you shortly</p>
{% endif %} {{ form.renderFormTag(url, {class: 'form service-request-form'}, {id: 'form service-request-form'})|raw }}```

I can't find a a $submit in the whole file or 'confirmation' amongst the PHP file for this form

Comment: i made that variable up (pseudo code like). Add an `else` to the `if` you are using and only render the form when there is no confirmation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this server side, then you can simply do:

```
{% if (confirmed) %}`
    <p>Thank you. The form has been hidden</p>
{% else %}
    <form>
        <input type='text'>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

Or, if you want to do this client side, then it is simple using jquery and you can hide the form by doing:

```
$("#form-id").hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the "myForm" id to  tag.

```
<form id="myForm">
```

Close the PHP tag one line before your message line printed in PHP, for example in case of contact form, like this.

```
//your ongoing code on click event of submit button
mail("mymail@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers, $email);
?>
<script>
$("#myForm").hide()
</script>
<?php 
echo "Message sent.";
?>
```

Another way to do it through CSS **(Tested, Working!)**

```
//your ongoing code on click event of submit button
mail("mymail@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers, $email);
?>
<style>
#myForm{display:none;}
</style>
<?php 
echo "Message sent.";
?>
```

Make sure to place this INSIDE THE CLICK function of the button. It should work!